# Remove "filename" header from FormData

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, multipartform-data, codeceptjs

I'm trying to post a request using FormData(), I need to include the "content type" header so I'm using the blob to append entries to my form, but this automatically sets the filename to "blob"

```
const formData = new FormData();

        const obj1 = new Blob([json_data], {type: 'text/plain; encoding=utf-8'});
        formData.append("small_config", obj1);

        const obj2 = new Blob([client], {type: 'text/plain; encoding=utf-8'});
        formData.append("app_type", obj2);

        const obj3 = new Blob([version], {type: 'text/plain; encoding=utf-8'});
        formData.append("product_version", obj3);

        let thumb = await fetch(my_url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
            body: formData
        });
```

Is there a way to both set the content type and not include filename?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have FormData not send a filename with an appended blob.  You can send an empty string however.

Use the 3rd parameter to `FormData.append`

```js
formData.append("small_config", obj1, 'My Filename');
```

So for your case, try an empty string.

```js
formData.append("small_config", obj1, '');
```

From Mozilla docs:

filename Optional 
The filename reported to the server (a USVString), when a Blob or File is passed as the second parameter. The default filename for Blob objects is "blob". The default filename for File objects is the file's filename.

Comment: This doesn't work, filename in formData entries is still "blob"

Comment: @BartoszWłodarczyk i posted another solution.

Comment: this results in formData with ' filename = "" '

Comment: Then there is your answer.  Blank filename or blob filename.  You can try to use null or undefined, but that is not part of the spec, needs to be a string.

Comment: Also, how is a blank filename not 'removing filename'?  Your backend is going to have to deal will missing or blank in a simliar manner.

Comment: I might've explained the problem wrong, I need the whole header to be gone, not just the value. For whatever reason just having the header there makes the request unusable.

Comment: You will have to not use FormData object then.  I updated the solution.

Comment: I just thought it might be possible, because it's really easy to do with python's requests library

Comment: You can do it, just need to manually send the content-disposition header and not use the FormData.

Comment: Is it possible this is related to incorrect 'content-type' from the blob, and not even related to the filename?  That is a common issue too, and you CAN override the content type.